# find the limit of the following function without using L'Hopital's Rule

Tags: limits-without-lhopital

Can help to solve the following limit without using L'Hopital's Rule?

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^x-x-1}{cosx-1}$$

Comment: expand cosine in Maclaurin series?

Comment: I tried the expansion for e^x and cosx, but I am not sure how it works

Comment: 7 minutes.$ $ $ $

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/387333/are-all-limits-solvable-without-lhôpital-rule-or-series-expansion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use taylor series$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^x-x-1}{cosx-1}=\\\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{(1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+...)-x-1}{(1-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{4!}-...)-1}=\\$$can you go on  ?
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+...}{(-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{4!}-...)}=\\
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x^2(\frac{1}{2!}+\frac{x^1}{3!}+...)}{x^2(-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{x^2}{4!}-...)}=\\$$simplify $x^2$
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{(\frac{1}{2!}+\frac{x^1}{3!}+...)}{(-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{x^2}{4!}-...)}=\\\frac{\frac12}{-\frac12}=-1$$

Comment: I am sorry I do not know how to continue..

Comment: @qsmy. Expand top and bottom and simplify.

Comment: oh ok thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

$$e^x=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+o(x^2)\implies e^x-1-x=\frac{x^2}{2!}+o(x^2)$$

$$\cos(x)=1-\frac{x^2}{2!}+o(x^2)\implies \cos(x)-1=-\frac{x^2}{2!}$$

Therefore, $$\frac{e^x-1-x}{\cos(x)-1}=\frac{1+\varepsilon_1(x)}{-1+\varepsilon_2(x)}$$
where $\varepsilon_i$ are function s.t. $$\lim_{x\to 0}\varepsilon_i(x)=0.$$